# How can i make divs with numbers change background colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know if I can change the background colour of the divs with numbers in a sequence so 1 goes first and then 2 then 3 with a function that will load automatically?

Here is the code that I have at the moment:
    
    
    
    Test

```
<!--JavaScript for Changing Colours-->
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

<!--Table Style-->
<style>
    body{
        background-color: #000000 ;
    }
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid #000000 ;
        background-color: #000000 ;
    }
    th,td{
        background-color: #303030 !important;
        width: 218;
        height: 72;
    }
    #table{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

</style>
</head>


<body>
<!-- Start of Table -->
<table id="table" >
<tr id="first">
    <th>&nbsp</th>
    <th>&nbsp</th>
    <th id="3">&nbsp</th> <!--Change to Blue-->
    <th>&nbsp</th>
</tr>
<tr id="second">
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td id="1">&nbsp</td>  <!--Change to Yellow-->
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td id="5">&nbsp</td>                  <!--Change to Orange-->
</tr>
<tr class="third">
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td id="2">&nbsp</td> <!--Change to Green-->
    <td>&nbsp</td>
</tr>
<tr id="fourth">
    <td id="4">&nbsp</td> <!--Change to White-->
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So why do you need javascript? Are you saying that you want a delay in when the background color changes? i.e change #1's color, wait some time, change #2's color, wait ... etc.

Comment: Yes i want a delay between colour one and two for exemple i want colour one to apear then disapear and colour 2 to apear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) and a counter to call a function and apply the background to each cell. You should also remove `!important` from the css if possible, as that makes it harder to override the background colour - it's a bit hacky and should be used as a last resort.

```
(function() {

    var i = 1;
    // put colours in an array, we don;t need anything in position 0, because there is no <td id="0">
    var colours = [null, 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'white', 'orange'];

    // the function to set the background
    function setColour() {
        // reset previous cell if there was one
        var previousTd = document.getElementById(i-1);
        if(previousTd != null) {
            previousTd.style.backgroundColor = '';
        }

        var td = document.getElementById(i);
        if(td != null) {
            td.style.backgroundColor = colours[i];
            i++;
            // wait half a second and call the function again
            window.setTimeout(setColour, 500);
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', setColour);

})();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jazwLbf2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **setTimeout** .

If you don't want to use jQuery.

```
   setTimeout(function() {

    document.getElementById("1").style.color = "yellow"

    },3000); // here 3000 is the timeinterval in milliseconds(1000 = 1sec)
```

and..

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, it may be a little simpler and jquery is better for cross-browser support:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(changeColor, 500);    
});
var a = 1;
var colors = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue"];
function changeColor() {
    $( "div" ).each(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "");
    });
    if (a > 4) { a = 1; }
    $("#" + a).css("background-color", colors[a - 1]);
    a++;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cdj87t9e/

Just change `$( "div" ).each` to `$( "td" ).each`

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Codepen with CSS animation** 
You can do this with css using flexbox.  Check it out on codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYLWMZ)

HTML

```
<table id="table" >
<tr id="first">
  <th><p>&nbsp</p></th>
  <th><p>&nbsp</p></th>
  <th id="three"><p>THREE</p></th> <!--Change to Blue-->
  <th><p>&nbsp</p></th>
</tr>
<tr id="second">
  <td><p>&nbsp</p></td>
  <td id="one"><p>ONE</p></td>  <!--Change to Yellow-->
  <td><p>&nbsp</p></td>
  <td id="five"><p>FIVE</p></td>                  <!--Change to Orange-->
</tr>
<tr class="third">
  <td><p>&nbsp</p></td>
  <td><p>&nbsp</p></td>
  <td id="two"><p>TWO<p></td> <!--Change to Green-->
  <td><p>&nbsp</p></td>
</tr>
<tr id="fourth">
  <td id="four"><p>FOUR</p></td> <!--Change to White-->
  <td><p>&nbsp</p></td>
  <td><p>&nbsp</p></td>
  <td><p>&nbsp</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background-color: #000000 ;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #000000 ;
    background-color: #000000 ;
}
th,td{
    background-color: #303030 !important;
    width: 218;
    height: 72;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#table{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;


}
tr{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;

}
td,th {
  order:2;
  flex-grow:1;
  text-align:center;
}
#three {
  order:1;
  color:#fff;
  background:blue !important;
}
#one {
  order:1;
  color:#333;
  background:yellow !important;
}
#two {
  order:1;
  color:#fff;
  background:green !important;
}
#five{
  order:1;
  color:#333;
  background:orange !important;
}
#four {
  order:1;
  color:#333;
  background:#fff !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `setTimeout` to do this. You *could* use `.css()` to just change the background color but I would suggest adding a `class` in the event that you ever wanted to add more CSS rules (also I would suggest changing your `id`'s to words instead of numbers, ex: `#one` instead of `#1`):

## [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L3syjLvd/1/)

**JS**

```
setTimeout(function(){
 
    $("#one").addClass("yellow");
    
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(){
 
    $("#two").addClass("green");
    
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function(){
 
    $("#three").addClass("blue");
    
}, 3000);

setTimeout(function(){
 
    $("#four").addClass("white");
    
}, 4000);

setTimeout(function(){
 
    $("#five").addClass("orange");
    
}, 5000);
```

**CSS**

```
.yellow{
    background-color: yellow;
}

.green{
    background-color: green;
}

.blue{
    background-color: blue;
}

.white{
    background-color: white;
}


.orange{
    background-color: orange;
}
```

### UPDATE

I noticed your comment about wanting them to fade in and out after I posted my anwser. To do this a lot simpler with jQuery (plain javascript can be very wordy) here is another solution using `setInterval`:

```
var counter = 0;
var colorArray = ["yellow","green", "blue", "white", "orange"];

setInterval(function(){

 $("#color"+(counter+1)).css({"background-color":colorArray[counter]});
 $('td,th').not("#color"+(counter+1)).attr("style", "");

 counter++;

}, 500);
```

## [**NEW FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/L3syjLvd/3/)